# Syncing data from memory process (C++) to database

Tags: c++, server

I have a C++ program that read game data from memory process. For example,

```
int points = 0;
while (1) {
 points = ReadProcessMemory(..) // points will be read from game's memory
 Sleep(100) // Don't read too often      
}
```

I want to sync the data so that it display this point (not necessarily real time but fast enough) on my website. So I have serveral option

1. In the while loop, kept sending POST request to server API to save to database
2. In the while loop, check for change in point, if detected then send POST (reduce server traffic)
3. In the while loop, write to database straight away so no traffic on server, only on database (Cloud server that is free)

Then on the server,

1. If Firebase is used then thing will be easy as data be binded automatically on changed.
2. If not Firebase, then make another while loop to keep refreshing?

I hope someone can give me some insight on how to make this efficient. Of course it will work if I just keep writing in the while loop on C++ program and keep reading in the while loop on the server. But I feel there is much better design. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am aware, that why I apologized. And in fact in the other post people were mentioning and even given a link that it is frowned upon to cross post. But I didn't want to delete the post with comments that's why I chose to try to explain my situation. I am not sure why I am suddenly get treated with sarcasm. Either you can tell me kindly. I am here to learn and earn more knowledge and not get discouraged by these actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the following requirements:

- it's game code, so it has to be reactive
- changes are monitored every 100ms.
- this processing speed of the chose option should cope with this frequency despite network and database latency.

On the client side:

- Option 1 would require 10 times per second: the preparation of POST (conversion to strings and concatenation) and the sending of HTTP request.
- Option 2 would mean 10 times per second:  comparison of the point with previous state (in memory comparison), and only when it differs doing the POST of option 1.  In the worst case (point is constantly changing), you would have almost the same load than for option 1 (memory comparison is negligible compared to the other operations). But most probably, you would have a faster response time.
- Option 3 would be very similar to option 1 (except that in otpion 1, the webserver would have to add another time the communication exercise, which could make a difference if you'd wait for completion)

So I'd suggest to go for option 2,  or eventually to an option 4:  posting changes only, but directly to the webserver.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am also concern that the traffic might be alot? If I keep on sending post request (50 kb) per post then that will incur alot of cost right?

Comment: @Zanko I can't tell about pricing, but if you pay for the traffic and there are many users, probably. Fortunately Option 2 and 4 avoid unnecessary traffic. Nevertheless if each single post is about 50 kb you should radically change your architecture and use an observer pattern to send only what's really needed